# Does snapper (creating btrfs snapshots) spin up or keep spun up my hdd?

Tags: debian, hard-disk, btrfs, snapper

I am concerned that:

1. snapper (when creating snapshots) might prevent my drive to go sleep or
2. when the drives are sleeping that snapper might wake them up?

If yes, how can I prevent that? My goal is that the drives go to sleep and stay sleeping and also benefit from snapper periodic snapshots.

I have two drives in raid 1 with a btrfs filesystem on them.

---

#### Scenario 1

I use snapper to create periodic snapshots every 30 minutes.
The two hdd drives should go to sleep via hd-idle after 3 hours of no use.

Will the drives ever go to sleep?

---

#### Scenario 2

Snapper creates periodic snapshots every 6 hours.
The two hdd drives should go to sleep via hd-idle after 3 hours of no use.

Will snapper wake the drives up when creating the periodic snapshots?

Comment: Well, it seems your approach is bad: doing regular snapshots makes no sense if you know a disk hasn't been used in the last snapshot interval; that snapshot would contain zero new information. So, the fixed-time approach makes no sense, conceptually.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want a snapshot to happen, then yes, you'll have to spin up your disk. So, how is that a problem that needs solving? If you only need the snapshots that contain useful information, then you will have to use your hard drives for them, whether you like it or not (modern disk don't care nearly as much as they did in the 1990s...)

Comment: @MarcusMüller not the answer I hoped for : ) In the end I might end up raising the snapshot timer from 1800 seconds up to 24h or several days. That might be the easiest approach for me then.

Comment: ... not the comment I was hoping for. The point is that making snapshots on a timer makes no sense on disks that you plan to suspend occasionally; on a longer timer even less so. Please try to re-read my comment above. **In other words,** consider what you're doing snapshots *for*; the point is *not* to have a snapshot at a regular interval, but to have a snapshot of a new state of your files at some sensible point in time. "Regular snapshots" only make sense on a continuously-used medium. Not if it sleeps. What you want to do is "stupid" (not you, only the plan to regularly do snapshots).

Comment: What use would having a snapshot in which *nothing* has changed since the last snapshot make? None. So, instead of doing snapshots every N minutes unconditionally, tell hd-idle (I'm surprised that is still a thing – I thought the problem it solves has long been solved) to do a snapshot before actually sending the suspend command to the disk(s). That makes much more sense. For the times where the disk is *not* idle, you can still do regular snapshots.

Comment: @MarcusMüller doing snapshots every day or every few days costs nothing. while your approach is way nicer it is way harder for me to set up.

Comment: well you are the one who is worried about the disk spinning up, which also costs nothing…

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am worried about permanent spinning disks and less about disks spinning up